# DIV positioning works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html, cross-browser, css-position

I have a problem positioning a DIV with Chrome on [this page](http://godfather.doesntexist.com/DiagMotorFinal/). When I enter text into the red DIV it moves it down (doesn't occur in Firefox).

[This shows](http://godfather.doesntexist.com/DiagMotorFinal2/) how it was before putting `why` into the red DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the boxes is not being considered for vertical alignment (perhaps because the height is applied by the id and the display:inline-block is being applies by a class?). To solve this just add vertical-align:top; to your .box class.

BTW, since the heights are all the same, it might be easier to just put these in a container div to control the width and use float:left;